# How do I get a higher resolution than 1280 X 800 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, resolution, inspiron

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Inspiron 1520 that has an nVidia G84M graphics card

I have followed the instructions from this link

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

and I installed the recommended nvidia-319 package but I am still stuck with 1280 x800 as the maximum resolution

running windows 7 in virtualbox I can get a resolution of 1600 x 1200 so the issue appears in Ubuntu

does anyone have any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Dell-Inspiron-1520-Notebook.5940.0.html) - your laptop's native resolution is 1280x800. It does not make much sense to use non-native resolution on an LCD display, but if you want to make everything smaller you can do it by using `xrandr` to scale your display.

See this question for more details: [How do I achieve higher resolution than physical resolution of an LCD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46211/how-do-i-achieve-higher-resolution-than-physical-resolution-of-an-lcd)

Comment: Thanks for the answers - its an old Laptop and I didn't check the resolution before I wiped out vista - I can understand why Ubuntu is running the resolution it is based on the LCD resolution - what confuses me is why the windows 7 virtualbox is defaulting to a higher resolution - ho hum - I'll reduce the reolution in windows 7 to match the Ubuntu resolution

Answer (score 0):

As my blog post, [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html), suggests

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1600x900_60.00"
sudo xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

1. First command creates a new mode with resolution 1600x900
2. Second command makes it available for use, with display (in this case VBOX0)
3. Third command selects the newly added mode as the display resolution for the specified display

To change this to any custom resolution, just replace 1600 with the width you want and 900 with the height you want.